# Using Protractor, how can I select a div with a unique class and test whether or not it's displayed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Here is the view.html of that unique class:

```
<div class="appExperience small-tile">
</div>
```

Here is the code I have tried:

```
var displayedTile = element(by.css('.appExperience small-tile'));

   expect(displayedTile.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

I get the following message when I run protractor

> Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, .appExperience small-tile)

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this  :

```
var displayedTile = element(by.css('div.appExperience.small-tile'));
```

OR

```
 var displayedTile = element(by.css('.appExperience.small-tile'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You getting this error:

> Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, .appExperience small-tile)

It might be because your selector looks wrong - if you want to search by 2 classes just put them all together with dots, like this:

```
var displayedTile = $('.appExperience.small-tile');
```

But if you locator is correct,
isDisplayed() will fail here if element not exist on page. Try to use isPresent() instead to verify that element not exist:

```
var displayedTile = $('.appExperience small-tile');
expect(displayedTile.isPresent()).toBeFalsy('Displayed Tile should not be present on the page.');
```